# Usage of upside down

Tags: adjectives

Can I say :

> A flask is upside down conical  in shape.
>
> The letter M is upside down the letter W in shape.
>
> The product is shaped like the letter V but upside down.
>
> The product is shaped like upside down the letter V.

---

I think upside down is adverb so I was wondering how it sounds when it is used in this way?

Comment: _The letter M is shaped like an upside-down W_ – that's how I'd write it. (The adjective form is often hyphenated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps, you can use the single word "inverted" in place of "upside down".  So, that would be:

> "A flask is an upside down cone in shape."  (okay)
>   "A flask is an upside down cone" / "A flask is an inverted cone"  (better)
>
> "The letter M is an upside down letter W in shape" (okay)
>   "The letter M is an inverted 'W'"  (better)
>
> "The product is shaped like the letter V but upside down."  <-  This is fine
>   "The product is shaped like an upside down letter V"

Comment: "Inverted" is certainly a valid alternative, but I wouldn't say it's better.

Comment: Let me just add: "Upside down" is an adjective phrase, not an adverb. It modifies a noun.

Comment: @Jay Thank you for your feedback. I looked it up again and noticed upside down is both adverb and adjective.

Comment: Let me re-phrase. It is an adjective phrase as you are using it here, and I think it is USUALLY used as an adjective. Yes, you could say, "The boat was floating upside down", that would be using it as an adverb. But I think that's less common.